# Looping through range of cells of a particular colour using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for help with a Macro which would loop through all the cells in a specified row (8).
However in order to complicate matters I'm only concerned with cells of a particular colour (Blue) as there are many cells in the 8th row but some are green.
In order to complicate matters even further of the subset of cells that are blue I only want to highlight those that contain the text "product", "UOM" or "Pack size" and "New Unit Price"
Once found I would like to highlight the columns which these cells are the headers of. I then would like to copy those cells and paste them into a new workbook.

It seems there are a few ways to do this, I could either loop through all the cells on the 8th row with the condition being highlight column If cell contains the specified text AND cell is blue. However this seems inefficient.
Or I could loop through all cells and stop once a green cell has been reached. This would give me the range of blue cells. I could then loop through the range of blue cells highlighting all columns for which the header contains the specified text.
I'm only new to VBA and don't really know the syntax terribly well. I also had trouble finding information on looping through cells which contain only a specified colour.
Anyone know how this could be done?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub HighlightColumns(ByVal w As Worksheet)
  Dim c As Range
  Dim found As Range

  For Each c In Application.Intersect(w.Rows(8), w.UsedRange).Cells
    If c.Interior.Color = vbBlue Then
      Select Case c.Value
      Case "product", "UOM", "Pack size", "New Unit Price"
        If found Is Nothing Then Set found = c Else Set found = Application.Union(found, c)
      End Select
    End If
  Next

  If Not found Is Nothing Then found.EntireColumn.Select
End Sub
```